# una expresion regular que no admita espacios al inicio y final en jsf vistas

Tags: java, jsf, jpa

Tengo esto, pero no puedo hacer que en el input no admita espacios al inicio y final, los espacios entre palabras si los necesito , hay alguna expresion que me pueda ayudar?

```
<p:inputText id="nombre" placeholder="Ej. Faros" value="#{catAgrupadorMBean.agrupador.nombre}"  
    required="true" requiredMessage = "El nombre del agrupador es requerido" validatorMessage="MAL" maxlength="70" />
    <f:validateRegex
    pattern="[[a-zA-Z0-9[:space:]]*$">
    </f:validateRegex>
    </p:inputText>
```

Comment: Lealo en el bean y le aplica un trim() al valor.

Comment: Pon una función onblur y manejelo con JS para no tener que sobrecargar al servidor.